# Is it possible to add QuickWatch Expression programatically when debugging in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

While debugging I constantly find myself adding

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request`

or similar to QuickWatch Expression (Shift+F9)...

Is there a way to do this in C# via code (some attribute or similar)?

Comment: Why not just add a watch instead of a quickwatch? That way it'll always be there across debugging sessions.

Comment: @vcsjones  How do you "add a watch" with certain expression so it is persistent across all debugging sessions (and VS restarts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a VS Macro that both adds the expression to the Watch window and open the QuickWatch window with it:

```
Sub WatchHttpRequest()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.AddWatch",   "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.QuickWatch", "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request")
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work me....I don't have DTE reference for some reason...

Comment: You'll need `Imports EnvDTE` at the top of the macro file. To quickly create a macro the easiest way is usually to record a new macro (ctrl+shift+R, do the action with keyboard or menus, then ctrl+shift+R). Then you can repeat the action with ctrl+shift+P. You can also edit the Temporary macro (Tools > Macros > Macros IDE) to copy the macro into a new source file to make it into a "permanent" macro. This can then be assigned to any keypress using Tools > Options > Keyboard.